# Bind more than one property in an element?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'd like to have a radio button select group, with the last option being "Other:" and a text input to specify another option. I thought I would be able to do this:

```html
<script>
    let options = ['a','b','c'];
    let selectedOption = 'a';
    let otherOption = ''
</script>

{#each options as option}
    <label>
        <input type=radio bind:group={selectedOption} name="selectedOption" value={option}>
        {option}
    </label>
{/each}
<label>
    <input type=radio name="selectedOption" 
           bind:group={selectedOption} 
           bind:value={otherOption} 
    />
    Other: 
    <input type=text bind:value={otherOption} />
</label>

{selectedOption}
<br/>
{otherOption}
```

The predefined options work well, the text input binds correctly to the `otherOption` variable, but when I select the last radio button `selectedOption` is `undefined`.

I suspect that this is because the `bind:value` directive is stepping over the `bind:group` one.

Is there an elegant way to bind both the group and the value attributes of a radio input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be selected if you drop the unnecessary `bind:` of the value:

```html
<input type=radio name="selectedOption" 
       bind:group={selectedOption} 
       value={otherOption} />
```

But note that the value will *not* be updated when you edit the field after the selection.

A better method would be to specify a concrete value for the "other" option and just resolve the selected value differently, e.g.

```js
$: selected = selectedOption == 'other' ? otherOption : selectedOption;
```

```html
<input type=radio name="selectedOption" 
       bind:group={selectedOption} 
       value="other" />
<!-- ... -->
{selected}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/816440ccb01a4a10b38ffddbc71f9456?version=3.50.1)